# how to make my ListView to open new activity

Tags: android, android-listview

this is my source code, please help me to make this list view link to new activity f.e SecondActivity.class, ThirdActivity.class and exit action

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
    {
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_cloudy, "Cloudy"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_showers, "Showers"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_snow, "Snow"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_storm, "Storm"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.weather_sunny, "Sunny")
    };

    WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listview_item_row, weather_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Whats is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent intent = null ;
                    switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    intent  = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);          
                    break;
                case 1:
                intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }


                }
            });
```

Comment: in case i have 5 activity and i use "case select" for open that activity, how to make that??? please help me

Answer (score 0):

> to make this list view link to new activity

for opening new Activity on ListView Click you will need to add `setOnItemClickListener` for ListView and inside `onItemClick` method you can open new Activity. do it as:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, 
                               View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
        // open new Activity here...

          Intent intent = new Intent(arg1.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
          arg1.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and also make sure you have add `SecondActivity` Activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onItemClickListener` to your listview see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29)

or if using `Fragments`, use the `ListFragment` and override the `onListItemClick` method